# Extract a value from Datatable and store to a collection in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to extract a value from the datatable and store to a collection. What would be the best way to do it?

The rows in my Datatable will have data like :

```
 Row 1          <configuration><Store parameter="Atribs">AB,CD</Store></configuration>

 Row 2          <configuration><Store parameter="Atribs">EF,GH,IJ</Store></configuration>

 ......
```

I want to retrieve and store the values in a collection like,

```
Collection 1 :
AB
CD

Collection 2 :
EF
GH
IJ

Collection ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```
var table = new DataTable();
            var column = new DataColumn("col1");

            table.Columns.Add(column);

            var row = table.NewRow();
            row[0] = @"<configuration><Store parameter=""Atribs"">AB,CD</Store></configuration>";
            table.Rows.Add(row);

            row = table.NewRow();
            row[0] = @"<configuration><Store parameter=""Atribs"">EF,GH,IJ</Store></configuration>";
            table.Rows.Add(row);

            var data = new List<List<string>>();

            foreach (DataRow dRow in table.Rows)
            {
                var temp = new List<string>();
                string xml = dRow.Field<string>("col1");

                var element = XElement.Parse(xml);
                string[] values = element.Descendants("Store").First().Value.Split(',');

                temp.AddRange(values);
                data.Add(temp);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You say a DataTable, but provided xml data in your example, so I am not sure.. bu basically, this is what you need to do:

```
var myList = new List<string>();

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    myList.Add(row.Field<string>("myCol"));
}
```

Something like that. It would be easier to give a better example if you could provide us with info about your DataTable and not your source xml file.  :)

Comment: XML is stored in my Datatable rows

Answer (score 0):

You might need to be a bit more clear on what you mean by "datatable" in that your example data is XML. Provided you know enough to fetch the rows from the data/xml:

Read each row and use String.Split() on the inner value to generate a string array which can be fed into a List.

```
var list = new List<string>(String.Split(",", innerData));
```

Of course you'll want to validate that the inner data has content.

Comment: Based on comment to previous answer: You've got two things to tackle. 1 - Parse the XML using XElement/XDocument. 2- Parse contents using the above example.

Comment: Can you provide me an example.